# How to combine Lat Long in CSV file with zone name in shapefile without any common identifier

Tags: shapefile, r

I have a CSV file that has Latitude, & Longitudes of various locations in NYC. I have related shapefiles that have the various zones names (like Battery Park, CentralPark etc)

Problem statement: I need to add a new column to the CSV file that has the zone name corresponding to each Lat Long pair.

Note:

1. The CSV file doesn't have any identifier common with shapefiles.
2. I am a newbie to R. Following is the code I have tried and after this I have no clue how to go about.

```
library(sqldf)
library(ggplot2)
library(rgdal)
library(data.table)
library(xtable)
library(tcltk)
library(rgeos)

points<-as.data.table(read.csv.sql(file,sql="select * from file where type=2 ",header=TRUE,sep=","))

zones<-readOGR("nyc_zones.shp", layer="nyc_zones")
proj4string(zone)
coordinates(points)<-~longitude+latitude
proj4string(points)
proj4string(points)<-CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83")
points<-spTransform(points,CRS(proj4string(zones)))
identical(proj4string(points),proj4string(zone))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is called *spatial join*. It is implemented in package `sp` as function `over()`. Seeing that you already have everything prepared nicely, it is quite simple.

```
points_with_zones <- over(points, zones[,"name"])
```

This will produce a data frame with the same number of rows as your layer of points. Now you can easily connect those two:

```
points$zoneName <- points_with_zones$name
```

Just replace `"name"` with the name of column containing zone names. You can also use column index.